# First and second fundamental form with rotational surfaces (check)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm working out some examples for surfaces in differential geometry. I was working out simple rotational surface, but I think I've done something wrong.
Let  $\gamma\left(t\right)$ a curve parametrized with length of arc and given by $$\gamma\left(t\right)=\left(a\left(t\right),\,0,\,b\left(t\right)\right)$$
Let us consider the rotational surface given by
$$\varphi\left(\theta,t\right)=R_{z}\left(\theta\right)\gamma\left(t\right)=\left(a\left(t\right)\cos\theta,\,a\left(t\right)\sin\theta,\,b\left(t\right)\right).$$. 
I then have tangent and normal vectors
$$ \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\theta}= \left(-a\left(t\right)\sin\theta,\,a\left(t\right)\cos\theta,\,0\right),$$
$$\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}= \left(\dot{a}\left(t\right)\cos\theta,\,\dot{a}\left(t\right)\sin\theta,\,\dot{b}\left(t\right)\right),$$
$$N= \left(\dot{b}\left(t\right)\cos\theta,\,\dot{b}\left(t\right)\sin\theta,\,-\dot{a}\left(t\right)\right).$$
So calculating the first and second fundamental form I should have $$E=\dot{a}\left(t\right)^{2}+\dot{b}\left(t\right)^{2}, \,\,F=0, \,\,G=a\left(t\right)^{2},$$
$$e=a\left(t\right)\left(\dot{a}\left(t\right)\ddot{b}\left(t\right)-\dot{b}\left(t\right)\ddot{a}\left(t\right)\right), f=0, g=a\left(t\right)^{2}\dot{b}\left(t\right).$$
And curvature
$$K=\frac{a\left(t\right)\dot{b}\left(t\right)\left(\dot{a}\left(t\right)\ddot{b}\left(t\right)-\dot{b}\left(t\right)\ddot{a}\left(t\right)\right)}{\dot{a}\left(t\right)^{2}+\dot{b}\left(t\right)^{2}}.$$
Now If I try with the torus as a special case then $$\gamma\left(t\right)=\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right),\,0,\,r\sin\left(t\right)\right).$$
And first and second fundamental forms are
$$E=r^{2}, \,\,F=0, \,\,G=\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2},$$
$$e=r^{2}\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right), f=0, g=\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}r\cos\left(t\right).$$
And therefore curvature is
$$K=r\cos\left(t\right)\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right).$$ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Didn't check all, but (1) the third component of $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \theta}$ should be zero, (2) it seems that you did not normalize $N$.

Comment: indeed the third component was 0, I copied wrong

Comment: For the normalization of N, I forgot to write that the curve was parametrized for length of arc so the the formula of N should be ok...

Comment: Did you really checked that the length of $N$ is one? Which curve was parametrized by arc length?

Comment: Yes I did, the curve $\gamma$ is the one parametrized by lenght of arc. Indeed we have $\dot{a}\left(t\right)^{2}+\dot{b}\left(t\right)^{2}=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue was that $\dot{a}\left(t\right)^{2}+\dot{b}\left(t\right)^{2}=1$
because the curve was parametrized for lenght of arc.
Then we had
$$ \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}= \left(\dot{a}\left(t\right)\cos\theta,\,\dot{a}\left(t\right)\sin\theta,\,\dot{b}\left(t\right)\right),$$
    $$\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\theta}= \left(-a\left(t\right)\sin\theta,\,a\left(t\right)\cos\theta,\,0\right),$$
$$ N= \left(\dot{b}\left(t\right)\cos\theta,\,\dot{b}\left(t\right)\sin\theta,\,-\dot{a}\left(t\right)\right).$$
First fundamental form was
$$ E=1, \,\,F=0, \,\,G=a\left(t\right)^{2},$$
and second fundamental form had an error
$$e=\dot{a}\left(t\right)\ddot{b}\left(t\right)-\dot{b}\left(t\right)\ddot{a}\left(t\right), f=0, g=a\left(t\right)\dot{b}\left(t\right).$$
Now the curvature is
$$K=\frac{\dot{b}\left(t\right)\left(\dot{a}\left(t\right)\ddot{b}\left(t\right)-\dot{b}\left(t\right)\ddot{a}\left(t\right)\right)}{a\left(t\right)}.$$
Case of the Torus:
$$ \gamma\left(t\right)=\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right),\,0,\,r\sin\left(t\right)\right).$$
And if we want $\gamma\left(t\right)$ to be parametrized for lenght of arc we need$r^{2}=1$
So that
$$E=1, \,\,F=0, \,\,G=\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2},$$
$$e=1, f=0, g=\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)r\cos\left(t\right).$$
 And the curvature is correctly
$$K=\frac{r\cos\left(t\right)}{R+r\cos\left(t\right)}.$$